# Sacar el porcentaje entr 2 montos en diferentes elementos jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito que no me devuelvan NaN. En `div.calculado` me debe poner el % de cada comparación(porcentaje descontado). No hay problema cuando es una sola operación, entonces lo que necesito es que sea cíclico(se conpare el primer price_sale con el pimer price_compare, en el siguiente div.element ocurra lo mismo) agradeceré su ayuda, espero haber sido claro.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $ve = $('.price_sale').text().split('S/. ').join('');
      $nor = $('.price_compare').text().split('S/. ').join('');
      $porc = $nor-$ve;
      $pare = $porc/($nor/100);
    $('.calculado').text($pare + '% DESCUENTO');

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">
PRIMERA COMPARACION
    <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
    <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
PRIMER RESULTADO
    <div class="calculado"></div>
  </div><br/>

<div class="element">
SEGUNDA COMPARACION
  <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
  <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
SEGUNDO RESULTADO
  <div class="calculado"></div>
</div><br/>

<div class="element">
TERCERA COMPARACION
  <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
  <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
TERCER RESULTADO
  <div class="calculado"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Marco, la pregunta no termina de quedar clara. Lee [ask] y edita la pregunta con la información y consejos que encontrarás allí. Y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general (y así ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: Hola, acabo de modificarlo, espero se entienda mejor, la verdad el error se nota solo al ejecutar el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios puntos a revisar. Puedes generar un **each** cuando tienes varios elementos similares, en este caso los div con clase element. Solo incluí el loop a tu misma función, y cambie el **.text()** de jQuery por el **innerHTML** de javascript para que pueda reconocer los indice de los elementos.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".element").each(function (idx, row) {
      $ve = $('.price_sale')[idx].innerHTML.split('S/. ').join('');
      $nor = $('.price_compare')[idx].innerHTML.split('S/. ').join('');
      $porc = $nor-$ve;
      $pare = $porc/($nor/100);
    $('.calculado')[idx].innerHTML = $pare + '% DESCUENTO';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">
PRIMERA COMPARACION
    <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
    <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
PRIMER RESULTADO
    <div class="calculado"></div>
  </div><br/>

<div class="element">
SEGUNDA COMPARACION
  <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
  <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
SEGUNDO RESULTADO
  <div class="calculado"></div>
</div><br/>

<div class="element">
TERCERA COMPARACION
  <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
  <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
TERCER RESULTADO
  <div class="calculado"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabía hacer esto, me salvaste.

Answer (score 1):

Checa este ejemplo, espero que te pueda ayudar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      
      //Itero .element
      //Recorro .element clase que contiene las demas clases
      $.each($('.element'),function(i,v){
        //utilizo el metodo find para buscar dentro del elemento actual
        // v = elemento iterado actualmente
        var priceSale = $(v).find('.price_sale').text().replace('S/. ','');   
        //Pongo replace para quitar S/.  y que lo pueda tomar como un numero
        //console.log(priceSale);
        var pricecompare = $(v).find('.price_compare').text().replace('S/. ','');   
        //Realizo los calculos
        //console.log(pricecompare);
        var porc = pricecompare - priceSale;
        //console.log(porc);
        var pare = porc/(pricecompare/100);
        console.log(pare);
        //Muestro el resultado en la clase calculado del elemento iterado actualmente
        $(v).find('.calculado').text(pare + ' %');
      });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="element">
PRIMERA COMPARACION
    <div class="price_sale">S/. 90.00</div>
    <div class="price_compare">S/. 10.00</div>
PRIMER RESULTADO
    <div class="calculado"></div>
  </div><br/>

<div class="element">
SEGUNDA COMPARACION
  <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
  <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
SEGUNDO RESULTADO
  <div class="calculado"></div>
</div><br/>

<div class="element">
TERCERA COMPARACION
  <div class="price_sale">S/. 99.90</div>
  <div class="price_compare">S/. 200.00</div>
TERCER RESULTADO
  <div class="calculado"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, muy bien explicado, se nota que soy demasiado novato, soy solo aficionado a la programacion.

Comment: Para ser solo aficionado vas muy bien, :)